# Redux-React: value returned by a dispatch function is not being passed to child component

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

I am new to react-redux actually so I just need some help trying to understand any syntactical or logical mistake I am making here...

Basically, I want to display the reports fetched from another server. Function 'fetchNames' handles that and function 'fetchdownloadable' creates a returns a link that allows to pass through authentication and download the report in pdf onClick.

So I debugged on console, and I believe that there is something wrong with the order of execution of the code... when i debug.. i noticed that :
fetchnames is executed first to fetch all report data in json array... 
then fetchDownloadable is called for each object in the reports array and that returns 'undefined' value on SampleChild... 
then SampleChild is executed with undefined value... 
and then we come back to execute the fetchDownloadable function that prints link value on the console and dispatches action on the reducer that returns the 'state' instead of 'action.reports_uri' in the reducer...

Thanks in advance!

**SampleParent.js**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { fetchNames, fetchDownloadable } from '../../actions/actions'
import SampleChild from '../ui/SampleChild'
class SampleParent extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.fetchDownloadLink = this.fetchDownloadLink.bind(this)
}
componentDidMount() {
    const { dispatch } = this.props
    dispatch(fetchNames())
}
fetchDownloadLink(uri){
    this.props.dispatch(fetchDownloadable(uri))
}
render() {
    return (<div><ul id="myUL">
                {this.props.reports.map((report) => (
                    <li><SampleChild
                            key={report.id}
                            label={report.label}
                            uri={this.fetchDownloadLink("http://localhost:8080/sample"+report.uri+".pdf")}
                        /></li>))}
            </ul></div>
    )}
}
function mapStateToProps(state) {
const { reports } = state
return {
    reports
}}
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(SampleParent)
```

**SampleChild.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
export default class SampleChild extends Component {
render() {
    const { key, label, uri } = this.props
    return (
    <div className="inside_SampleChild" id={label}>
        {label}
        <a href={uri}><img src="../images/pdf-file_128.png" height="25px" width="25px"></img></a>
    </div>
    )}}
```

**Action.js**

```
import C from '../constants'
import fetch from 'isomorphic-fetch'  

export const fetchNames = value => dispatch => {
var obj = { method: 'GET', headers: { 'Authorization': 'Basic ***', 'Accept': 'application/json' },
    'credentials': 'include'};
fetch('http://localhost:8080/samplelink', obj)
    .then(response => {
        if (response.status !== 200) {
            throw Error(response.status);
        }return response;})
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then(resourceLookup => {
        var arr = [];
        var length = resourceLookup.resourceLookup.length;
        for(var i = 0 ; i< length ; i++){
            arr.push(resourceLookup.resourceLookup[i]);}
        dispatch({
            type: C.FETCH_LIST_REPORTS,
            reports: arr})}).
catch(error => {
    console.log("There was this  error" + error);});}

export const fetchReportDownloadable = (uri) => dispatch => {
var obj = {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Basic ***=',
        'Accept': 'application/json'
    },
    'credentials': 'include'
};
fetch(uri, obj)
    .then(response => {
        if (response.status !== 200) {
            throw Error(response.status);
        }
        return response ;
    })
    .then((response) => response)
    .then(resourceLookup => {
        console.log(`resourceLookup URL: ${resourceLookup.url}`)
        dispatch({
            type: C.FETCH_DOWNLOADABLE,
            report_uri: resourceLookup.url
        })
    }).
catch(error => {
    console.log("There was this  error" + error);
});}
```

**Reducers.js**

```
import C from '../constants'
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
export const links = (state=null, action) =>
(action.type === C.FETCH_DOWNLOADABLE) ?
    action.report_uri :
    state
export const reports = (state=[], action) => {
switch(action.type) {
    case C.FETCH_LIST_REPORTS :
        return action.reports
    default :
        return state
}}
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
reports,
links
})
export default rootReducer
```

Comment: In SampleChild, try logging if the component receives new props in `componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps)`. trying logging nextProps and see if the uri is received there.

Comment: can someone help me understand the order of execution here please..? then mayb i'll be able to figure out the changes to be made... I am following this example.. http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/ExampleRedditAPI.html

Comment: In your action, in the dispatch function:
```dispatch({
            type: C.FETCH_DOWNLOADABLE,
            report_uri: resourceLookup.url
        })```, but you're assigning `action.report` in the reducer, that is undefined, try changing it to `action.report_uri`.

Comment: oh.. yes i did that just now.. but my link is still not clickable... the uri is still being passed as undefined in Samplechild component... also i tried printing d output of my action creator func 'fetchReportDownloadable', and it is printing the correct value at line 'console.log(`resourceLookup URL: ${resourceLookup.url}`)'

Comment: I have updated my answer, you can check it out now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will try explaining what is happening.

First, the first problem you have is that your passing a wrong value, or either undefined value of `uri` in:

```
<li>
  <SampleChild key={report.id} label={report.label}
     uri={this.fetchDownloadLink("http://localhost:8080/sample"+report.uri+".pdf")}
                        />
</li>
```

Here `uri` is a function, that triggers on the first render, it dispatches the `fetchDownloadable(uri)` action, it does not return any value however. Hence the `uri` is undefined.

Secondly, you have `C.FETCH_REPORT_DOWNLOADABLE` constant used in your reducer. However you never dispatch an action of that type, the action dispatches `C.FETCHING_DOWNLOADABLE`. Hence the reducer does not do anything really, so the state does not change. My second comment was about `C.FETCH_LIST_REPORTS`, which is irrelevant for you right now, so I was wrong about that.

What I would do, is create the download link from the server side. Send it back with the report object. This way, you won't need to dispatch two actions to list your reports. Then, I will dispatch my action in `componentWillMount()`, once it's done fetching the data, the state will be changed - if, again, you have dispatched the correct action - and you will have your reports with the download URL in the same object.

**Update**

Okay I think that I understand now. What I would do then is to send the `uri` as string to `SampleChild`, and then when it mounts I will trigger the `fetchDownloadable`function.

**SampleParent**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { fetchNames, fetchReportDownloadable } from '../../actions/actions'
import SampleChild from '../ui/SampleChild'
class SampleParent extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.fetchDownloadLink = this.fetchDownloadLink.bind(this)
}
componentDidMount() {
    const { dispatch } = this.props
    dispatch(fetchNames())
}
fetchDownloadLink(uri){
    this.props.dispatch(fetchReportDownloadable(uri))
}
render() {
    return (<div><ul id="myUL">
                {this.props.reports.map((report) => (
                    <li><SampleChild
                            key={report.id}
                            label={report.label}
                 uri={"http://localhost:8080/sample"+report.uri+".pdf"}
                 download={this.fetchDownloadLink}
                    /></li>))}
            </ul></div>
    )}
}
function mapStateToProps(state) {
const { reports } = state
return {
    reports
}}
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(SampleParent)
```

**SampleChild**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
export default class SampleChild extends Component {
componentDidMount() {
    this.props.download(this.props.uri);
}
render() {
    const { key, label, uri } = this.props
    return (
    <div className="inside_SampleChild" id={label}>
        {label}
        <a href={uri}><img src="../images/pdf-file_128.png" height="25px" width="25px"></img></a>
    </div>
    )}}
```

What is supposed to happen now is that you will fetch the reports first in `SampleParent` then pass the information to `SampleChild`. Whenever a `SampleChild` is mounted, it will trigger `fetchDownloadable` action which in returns download the `uri` sent to it.

Comment: Hi Mamdoh.. thanks for catching the error in reducer... i have corrected that now... about calling both functions in the same dispatch.. I am not sure i can do that as I need fetchNames() to return me 'reports' json array, and for each object in that array I am calling 'fetchDownloadable'.. can u clarify a little more here...

Comment: you're called `fetchDownloadable` inside of the `uri` prop in SampleChild, `uri` prop expects a string, and it is getting nothing, because `fetchDownloadable` returns nothing. 

Uhm what I meant was to get your reports fully ready before dispatching the action, and by that I mean getting the reports, and then getting the report download URL for each report. once you have your reports ready, then dispatch `C.FETCH_LIST_REPORTS` for example and assign the new reports to the reducer.

Comment: also what i thnk is that there is something wrong with the order of execution of the code... when i debug.. i notice that fetchnames is executed first to fetch all report data in json array... then fetchDownloadable is called for each object in the reports array and that returns 'undefined' value on SampleChild... then SampleChild is executed with undefined value... and then we come back to execute the fetchDownloadable function that prints link value on the console and dispatches action on the reducer that returns the 'state' instead of 'action.reports_uri' in the reducer...

Comment: yes your call is right... fetchDownloadable does not return anything... how can i make it return a string as expected i am still not clear ..

Comment: Can you update the question to show me the action that dispatches `FETCH_LIST_REPORTS`?

Comment: updated action.js file to include the function 'fetchnames'

Comment: Uhm, I am confused now. Since you already have your reports download URL, you want to download them too? or just link them to your component? I mean the logical thing to do is to link them to your component, if so you do not need `fetchDownloadable`. But again, I cannot fully understand what you need to do here.

Comment: Hey thnk u so much for the help! Just clarifying.. so each time we hit the link, it does not directly hit the "uri" parameter passed to it as prop right? It goes through the function first for authentication and then downloads?

Comment: Yes, it goes through `fetchReportDownloadable` action, which uses fetch with authentication ti download the file.

Comment: Hi Mamdoh.., i appreciate your help but i checked it still not passing through the function.. it accesses the link directly